# No history when using bash inside emacs?

Tags: bash, emacs, history

I've started using m-x term (with bash) inside emacs, but I noticed that if I use up arrow / down arrow I just get 'A' and 'B' respectively instead of my history.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Works for me in emacs23.

Comment: What you're actually getting is `^[[A` and `^[[B` which indicates that  your readline bindings are getting dropped for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was either a bug or lack of feature in Emacs 21.3.1, because when I recently got a second machine with Emacs 23.1.1 as the default install, I no longer see this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl-n`, `Ctrl-p` will go back and forth in the history of `term`, up and down will work on `M-x eshell`.

Answer (score 3):

when I use `M-x term` in emacs(23.3.1),I can use C-n,C-p or up arrow,down arrow to get history.

when I use `M-x shell`,I can use M-n,M-p to get the command history.

Answer (score 2):

You can use m-x shell

That supports previous and next command with m-p and m-n